# What is the relativity between ECDSA public keys, if any?

Tags: public-key, ecdsa

Wondering if there is any relative connection between public keys?

I know that they are a function of G, but is there any other connection they share?

Is it possible to calculate how many G are between two public key points?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question if, given two points *A* and *B*, you can compute *x* such that *A + xG = B*, the answer is no.

That would be equivalent to solving ECDLP (elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem), which is assumed to be computationally infeasible: just apply it with *A* a public key of your own (which you know the private key to), and *B* the point whose DL you want to compute. The resulting *x* plus the DL of *A* is the DL of *B*.